# phonegap, Strophe.js and xmpp pubsub push notifications when app is offline

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cordova, xmpp, openfire

What is the best way to be notified via push notification mechanisms when an update is published to a pubsub node (openfire server) and the xmpp mobile client app is offline? Should the app launch in the background say every 30 minutes without user knowing it (How would I achieve that)?
I'm building a Jquery mobile app and want to use phonegap to package it for iOS, android and maybe other devices.

Edit1: I think it should be something like C2DM or APNS. But how do I send a message from openfire server to C2DM/APNS when a particular user receives a message.

Edit2: How an XMPP server (e.g. openfire) would know whether to send the Push notification to the APNS or C2DM (because one user could have an Android or IOS device or both but the xmpp server doesn't know that)? If I'm asking the wrong questions, please correct me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Natively, an XMPP server doesn't know anything about those protocols so it cannot push to them.  You could create a plugin to push via some other means, but I think it would be simpler if you can get your client to connect every so often and get it's offline messages.

Comment: I hope such apps will not be rejected by apple :)

Comment: I think if Apple want to reject any app they'll easily find a reason to :)